# How can I find an address in a large file with grep?

Tags: grep

I've got an exercise to do in which I have been given a fictional email record in which the owner of the email got invited to a certain place for vacation.
The log is large though, so to speed things up, I have to use `grep` in a certain way to find the address where the owner of the email address is heading.

The basic form of how an address is written as:

```
name firstName
streetName streetNumber
postalCode(zip) City
```

Now I know that postal codes usually are 5 digits long, so I can start looking for the line with the postal code. Until now, I did it like this:

```
grep -C2 ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] emails
```

This command gives me all lines that start with 5 digits in a row and its surrounding two lines (`-C2`). With this I was really able to find the address, yet there's still a lot of unnecessary lines that show up around it. I have to specify the search to only get the address.

So I tried searching for a line that starts with 5 digits and ends with any letter like this:

```
grep -C2 ^´[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]$´ emails
```

But it ends up finding nothing. It's probably because it searches for a line that only contains 5 characters and a letter. But I don't know how to tell `grep` to search for a line that only searches for a line that *starts* with 5 digits **AND** *ends* with a letter (or even better, a word).

My next best try would be searching for the name and the first name by searching for a line which contains only two words. But I don't know how to do that and I can't find any discussion in which this is explained.

I hope you guys can help me out, please?

Comment: Can you include some actual examples of real data,  because I don't understand the details.  Give a working example of what you have to find, what you have to find it in, and what you want to output.

Comment: You should be using the word "character" where you've used "cipher".

Comment: Your final grep statement does exactly what you thought it did -- "starts with 5 digits AND ends with a letter". It will *not* match a line that ends in a word, because you've told grep you want *one* letter and then the end of the line.

Comment: @symcbean I noticed that too and tried to adjust it to what I thought they meant.

Comment: @symcbean Yeah but if I change it to character that means that it could also be a letter but i need 5 "ciphers"(numbers)

Comment: @EightBitTony 
let's say we have an email history:

Frank:
Hey Giselle,
how are you doing? We haven't had a chat for a long time now. How is your dog doing[...]

Giselle:
It's really been a long time. My dog's doing fine[...]

(They chat a lot about trivial things... And somewhere in all this trivial text comes this...)

Frank:
Yeah, why don't you come for a visit? Here, I'm giving you our address:

Frank Sahwit
Pattystreet 5
77860 Pallet Town

Giselle:
Oh i would love to[...]

(A lot of other trivial text following...)
Now I want to search this email history and find the address datas in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -B2 -E '^[0-9]{5} +[a-zA-Z]+$'` to try to find only address blocks.

Some notes:

- see `man grep` to get an understanding of the options
- see the end of the manpage for grep to find a manpage that explains the regex syntax in detail, the GNU grep manpage itself also explains regex a little
- `-B` is "lines before the match" and might be better suited for you than `-C`
- `-E` is for extended regex syntax
- the regex I gave matches any line that has five digits (`{5}` takes the preceding thing five times), then at least one space (`+` takes the preceding thing one or more times) and then only letters till the end of the line.
- take care how you quote your arguments to grep. `` ` `` is **very** different from `'` or `"`.

You can try to find lines containing only two words if you try to find lines that contain only one space:

```
grep -E '^[^ ]+ [^ ]+'
```

If you want to match something over multiple lines I am not sure if `grep` can do it. You could try to do it with `sed` which can load the next lines into the pattern space with `N` and then match against that concatenation (have a look at `man sed` if that might suit you). (Or `perl`, I think it can match multi line patterns but I don't know how.)

Answer (score 0):

> So I tried searching for a line that starts with 5 digits and ends with any
>   letter like this:

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]$
```

That pattern matches lines that contain *only* 5 digits and a (capital) letter.  If you expect there to be more between them, you will need to include it in the pattern.  If you don't care what goes between them, use `.*` to match any character, unlimited times.  You should probably also include lower-case letters, or use `grep -i` to ignore case.

```
^[0-9]\{5\}.*[A-Za-z]$
```

> My next best try would be searching for the name and the first name by
>   searching for a line which contains only two words. But I don't know how to
>   do that and I can't find any discussion in which this is explained.

You could match lines that contain two simple words, with a pattern that runs: start, word, gap, word, end:

```
^[[:alpha:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[[:alpha:]]\+$
```

However, attempting to match a name with a regular expression has many pitfalls.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name .